# MySQL access denied from bash when executing MySQL commands

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, unix

When I log in to mysql from a bash script such as this:

```
mysql --user="$USERNAME" --password="$PASSWORD" --database="$DATABASE" << EOF
# No command here
EOF;
```

My user is logged into the database and it works fine. But when my bash script does something as simple as

```
mysql --user="$USERNAME" --password="$PASSWORD" --database="$DATABASE" << EOF
show tables;
show columns from some_table;
...
# Now there are commands
EOF;
```

Mysql gives me this error: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'database'
What would cause this?

To clarify, I'm perfectly able to just call `mysql -uUser -pPass database` from the command line, log in, then call `show tables;`.  It's only when run from a bash script, and when that bash script includes a mysql command does my access get denied.

Furthermore is there a simple-to-use library for python/c++ that handles mysql interaction and doesn't involve having to sign up for something in order to obtain the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use the `-e` flag for passing commands in a script:

```
  mysql --user="$USERNAME" --password="$PASSWORD" --database="$DATABASE"  -e "show tables;"
```

Comment: I'm actually calling more than one command, sorry for not specifying, for that reason I'm using the << operator.

Comment: @kjh you can specify as many command you want separated by a semicolon

Comment: Ah ok. I'll go ahead and give this a try. does it ignore newlines?

Comment: I'd assue so as long as the starting quote is on the same line as the -e

Comment: It should still work as the question wrote it. `mysql` will read from stdin if there's no `-e` option, and I have many scripts that pipe to `mysql`.

Comment: @Barmar I've piped files of SQL into mysql with a single `<` , but never a block of text like the delimited  block above.  Can you post and example of it working with delimited text?

Comment: I just tried it as written in the original question, it worked just fine for me.

Comment: @Ray, your solution worked. I'll admit I'm not sure why. Is it possible that mysql would refuse to log me in if I am trying to execute a command that I don't have permission for? Or would it log me in and then inform me that I don't have permissions to execute the query.

Comment: The only distinction mysql makes is whether stdin is a terminal or not; if it's a terminal it displays the `mysql>` prompt, otherwise it just reads stdin and executes it.

Comment: @kjh I'm not sure how to use shell delimiters, but I know something simple like this fails.  It might work with `<<<` instead of `<<`

Comment: no I just write EOF after the << and EOF at the end of the mysql query

Comment: Ok dumb mistake here. A colleague of mine is looking the code over and realized that I when I copied this file for testing, I changed a command "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE" to "CREATE TABLE". I have permission to make a table but not a temporary one in our database apparently. That's what my original question should have been about. I just hadn't noticed the slip. Now it works both with << and the -e or --execute= arguments. Thanks for the help guys